# Unable to control requests for static files on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My simple GAE app is not redirecting to the /static directory for requests when url is multiple levels.

Dir structure:

```
 /app/static/css/main.css
```

App:

I have two handlers one for /app and one for /app/new

app.yaml:

```
handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /app/static/(.*)
  static_dir: static\1

- url: /app/.*
  script: app.py
  login: required
```

HTML:

Description:
When page is loaded from /app HTTP request for main.css is successful

```
 GET /static/css/main.css
```

But when page is loaded from /app/new I see the following request:

```
GET /app/static/css/main.cs
```

That's when I tried adding the /app/static/(.*) in the app.yaml but it is not having any effect.

Comment: How are you specifying the CSS file in whatever template is being rendered at `/app/new`?  It should (probably) be something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">` (note the "/" at the beginning of the `href` attribute).

Comment: Awesome!!! I changed to include the "/" at beginning and it worked!! was that why it was not matching the app.yaml handlers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML an internal link starting with "/" is an absolute link, a link starting without a "/" is a relative link. So if you are requesting:

**/app**

and have a relative link:

**static/css/main.css**

the request becomes:

**/static/css/main.css**

the relative link uses the "/" in "/app" because the "app" part is considered to be the page and the "/" is considered to be the directory.

If you are requesting:

**/app/new**

Your request becomes:

**/app/static/css/main.css**

the relative link uses the "/app/" because "/app/" is considered the directory and "new" is considered the page.